# JavaScript to Python (Using JS2PY)

Tags: javascript, python

I have a seed-calculating thing that uses JavaScript (Functions properly). I'm attempting to convert it into Python (For a more detailed project) using the JS2PY library.

My code:

```
import js2py

hasCode = js2py.eval_js('function hashCode(s) {let h = 0; for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {h = (Math.imul(31, h) + s.charCodeAt(i)) | 0;} return h;}')
getSeed = js2py.eval_js('function getSeed(s) {let x = BigInt(hashCode(s)); if (/^[\-\+0-9]*$/.test(s)) {try {let y = BigInt(s); if (BigInt.asIntN(64, y) !== y) {throw RangeError();} x = y;} catch (err) {}} return { high: x >> 32n, low: BigInt.asIntN(32, x) };}')
output = js2py.eval_js('function output() {let seed = -734744700160476640; print("Copy this output - " + seed.high, seed.low);}')

output()
```

Should you use this in, say, a HTML file, the JavaScript will produce a "High" and "Low" of the seed input (Here it is -734744700160476640, but I would allow users to input their own seed).

The command log explains that there's syntax errors in files that I'm assuming is from the library. You can probably tell I'm a little inexperienced so if it's my own code that's broken, shout it out. I don't know if JS2PY is outdated or if there's better options out there. I couldn't find any myself.

Comment: "JavaScript (Functions properly)" I find that unlikely, your seed value is two orders of magnitude smaller than `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER`. As for converting to Python, why not just do it by hand?

Comment: I would be more than happy to give you that very script in its own JavaScript file to prove to you it works. As for converting, like I said I'm inexperienced with so I wouldn't know where to begin with a Python version

Comment: Check the output of `-734744700160476640 + 1` or `-734744700160476640 - 1` in your browser console or the node command prompt. You sticking with that story? Also, if you're so inexperienced that you're asking strangers for help on the internet (and it's totes fine if you are) why are you *attempting (and failing) to correct them*?